# Regular Expression for a middle string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract from the below string

`2_240219_0.vnd` as `240219`

I have tried as follows: `_[0-9]+_`

This gives me `_240219_`

How do I remove the `_` from both ends.

Comment: Try Regex: `(?<=_)\d+(?=_)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDRfvt/1)

Comment: `Regex.Match(s, @"_([0-9]+)_").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: @Matt.G: thanks for the quick response it's perfect, post it as answer and also please explain briefly. thanks

Comment: If 2_240219_0.vnd is standard format of the string you will get everytime, you can simply use "2_240219_0.vnd".Split("_")[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually recommend not even using regex in this case.  A simple string split on underscore should do just fine:

```
string input = "2_240219_0.vnd";
string middle = input.Split('_')[1];
Console.WriteLine(middle);

240219
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a other regex: `([\d]{6,})`

```
Match m = Regex.Match(2_240219_0.vnd, `([\d]{6,})`, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```